# Next js creates different mysql connection pools if behind nginx

Tags: mysql, nginx, next.js, connection-pooling

this is my first question, hope I do it right!

I'm actually working on a Centos server with nginx as reverse proxy and a NextJs web application.

Until now I've made a single connection for every query to my db, but I want to switch to pool connection to my DB (with npm module `mysql2`), but apparently there's something I'm missing...

If I run my application local, or on the server without nginx, with `yarn start`, it opens just one pool (I can see them by running the query `SHOW PROCESSLIST` on the DB in use). But in the moment I add nginx as reverse proxy, every request my app receives opens a pool and the latter never gets closed or called again (apart from the one pool opened if someone visits the page for which I use the nextjs function `router.push(/url)`).

It happens also if I run `yarn dev`: it opens a connection pool for every new page next has to build in development or if I make some changes to pages and save. But this behaviour I understand.

The nginx configuration is a normal configuration, and everything works fine.

I've surfed the web far and wide, but didn't find anything that could help me understand what could be going on between nginx-next-mysqldb, and no one reported any problem whatsoever. Is this how it's supposed to be or there's something that I should do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Oops... my bad...
Transitioning from single db connections to pool, I left a function which made a single connection, which I was not closing.

So there's no problem and nothing to uncover behind nginx-next-mysql.

Don't know if anyone will stumble upon this problem, ever, but, just make sure you don't have any single connection to your db... And make sure to close them :)